# Motion capture in Blender

Tags: animation, tracking

Is it possible to do motion capture in Blender? Basically where someone will have a bunch of sensors on them and the person, or objects motion get's turned into 3D motion.

Comment: If you have the suit you will have to make an add-on that will be able to receive the data from the sensors and translate it to rotation of the bones.

Comment: This could, in theory, be done with the motion tracker, but I wouldn't expect much out of it, because it's designed to track camera motion, and basic object motion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NiMate, it's an addon that let's you motion capture with a Microsoft Kinnect and use the data in Blender.

http://www.ni-mate.com/use/blender/

[image]

Comment: it's good,but it costs 10 $ at month. Am I sure that there is some kind of open source alternative.